# How to setup host name for my website in compute engine

Tags: dns, google-compute-engine, plesk

I gone through the steps in https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/setting-up-dns, Added records in Parallel plesk panel. Still I am not getting the app page. 
The capture12 image file shows cloud DNS records.
The capture13 image file shows parallel plesk panel DNS records.

Thanks.[google cloud DNS records[parallel plesk panel DNS records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1pt0.png)

Comment: Can't get your use case, why you need plesk if you are going to use AppEngine? Just change DNS records in your domain's registrar interface.

Comment: @OlegNeumyvakin, where did the OP mention AppEngine? The questions seems entirely about **Compute** engine -- what am I missing?

Comment: OP, no capture12 nor capture13 files anywhere in sight -- the one URL you give, http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1pt0.png , is just one image -- and of course we have no way to verify that the IP it shows is correct -- visiting the IP shows a bitnami tomcat hello page, `host` and `dig` resolve the domain you give to a different IP authoritatively served by domaincontrol.com. BTW, don't you think this Q would work better on serverfault.com ...?